# Why is this not working? - Trying to save properties in a variable for use multiple times in a function

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am trying to find a way to save the properties for a `select` statement in PowerShell but it isn't working.  I haven't found a way to make an entire statement a literal so that it isn't reviewed until the variable is opened.

Here is what works:

```
$wsus.GetSummariesPercomputerTarget($CurrentMonthUpdateScope, $ComputerScope) |
    Select-Object @{L="WSUSServer";E={$Server}},
        @{L="FromDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.FromCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
        @{L="ToDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.ToCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
        @{L='Computer';E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetID)).FullDomainName}},
        DownloadedCount,
        NotInstalledCount,
        InstalledPendingRebootCount,
        FailedCount,
        Installedcount |
    Sort-Object -Property "Computer"
```

and I am trying to get the properties mentioned (starting just after the `Select-Object` statement and ending just before the last pipe) placed in a variable so that I can use the same properties multiple times with different scopes.

I have tried this:

```
$Properties = '@{L="WSUSServer";E={$Server}},
@{L="FromDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.FromCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
@{L="ToDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.ToCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
@{L="Computer";E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetID)).FullDomainName}},
DownloadedCount,
NotInstalledCount,
InstalledPendingRebootCount,
FailedCount,
Installedcount'

$wsus.GetSummariesPercomputerTarget($CurrentMonthUpdateScope, $ComputerScope) |
    Select-Object $Properties |
    Sort-Object -Property "Computer"
```

While this runs it doesn't give any data and I think it confuses PowerShell.

This gives the same response:

```
$Properties = "@{L=`"WSUSServer`";E={$Server}},
@{L=`"FromDate`";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.FromCreationDate).ToString(`"MM/dd/yyyy`")}},
@{L=`"ToDate`";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.ToCreationDate).ToString(`"MM/dd/yyyy`")}},
@{L=`"Computer`";E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetID)).FullDomainName}},
DownloadedCount,
NotInstalledCount,
InstalledPendingRebootCount,
FailedCount,
Installedcount"
```

Any options, thoughts, etc.?

Comment: Look at the value of your `$Properties` variable and you should see the problem right away. Single-quoted strings do not interpolate `$(...)` expressions. You'll need to use a double-quoted string instead (and escape your embedded quotes with backticks).

Comment: I tried it with double-quotes as well and it gives the same response.

Comment: Update: I updated the original question to include the $Properties using double-quotes and backticks - same response as the first version...

Comment: Can you try splatting it into one big @{}. Rather than using the calculated properties format, use the splatting format with script blocks?

For example:

$Properties = @{'WSUSServer'='$Server';
                           'FromDate'='{$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.FromCreationDate).ToString(`"MM/dd/yyyy`")}';
 
                           }
I'm not sure if it works. More info on splatting here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Property` argument of `Select-Object` expects an array, not a string. So something like this:

```
$Properties = @(@{L="WSUSServer";E={$Server}},
                @{L="FromDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.FromCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
                @{L="ToDate";E={$($CurrentMonthUpdateScope.ToCreationDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},
                @{L="Computer";E={($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetID)).FullDomainName}},
                "DownloadedCount",
                "NotInstalledCount",
                "InstalledPendingRebootCount",
                "FailedCount",
                "Installedcount")
```

Note, you will need to turn the simple property names into strings within your array.

Comment: So essentially you would be wrapping all of the items in the properties variable into a array using the @(...).  Is that correct (or am I missing something else there)?  I suppose I don't need the backticks in that example (they were only there to escape the double-quotes.

Comment: That worked (after removing the backticks).  Thanks!

Comment: The `@()` is optional. A comma-separated list would suffice. The important part is to not put the whole list in quotes (so that it doesn't become a single string).